# ByteString expects different ByteString

Tags: http, haskell, bytestring, http-conduit

This code doesn't typecheck:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

main :: IO ()
main = do
  resp <- simpleHttp "http://www.google.com"
  putStrLn $ BS.unpack resp
```

Throws the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `BS.ByteString'
            with actual type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
In the first argument of `BS.unpack', namely `resp'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `BS.unpack resp'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ BS.unpack resp
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How to fix this ? Changing to other ByteString variant doesn't work.

The type of `simpleHttp` function is like this: `simpleHttp
  :: Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m =>
     String -> m Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString`. So I try to get the ByteString within the IO monad and try to `unpack` it, but this results in an error.

Comment: what's about `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS` ?

Comment: @viorior It throws a different type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate ByteString modules, one for lazy ByteStrings and one for strict ByteStrings. simpleHTTP returns a lazy bytestring but you imported the strict bytestring module so unpack is expecting a strict bytestring.

Try changing

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
```

to

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS
```

---

That said, you need to be careful if you use the Char8 version of the bytestring modules, since the String <-> ByteString conversions only work if you use ASCII encoding. I would recommend [converting your bytestrings to Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html) with an appropriate encoding function and then printing that.

Comment: Changing it to `Lazy` throws a different error: "Couldn't match type `GHC.Word.Word8' with `Char'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [GHC.Word.Word8]
    In the return type of a call of `BS.unpack'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `BS.unpack resp'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ BS.unpack resp
Failed, modules loaded: none."

Comment: @Sibi: That word8 stuff has to do with using the the char8 version of the module or not. See my edit.